# Is it possible to declare a property which class is either 'A' or 'B'? (multiple class possibilites)

Tags: ios, objective-c, types, variable-declaration

In objective-C, is it possible to do something like the following?

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) <UIWebView or WKWebView> *webView;
```

In this case I know I can use `UIView` or even `id`, but I think the scope is too broad.

Thanks!

Comment: [link](https://gowithfloat.com/2014/12/one-webview-to-rule-them-all/) hope it help you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you would do that via class inheritance and declare the property to be of type *base class*, which is the super class of the view classes you want to support:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) SomeBaseView *webView;
```

You *could* declare the property to be of *any type* (`id`), however that would require additional testing when actually using the instance, in order to avoid *unrecognized selector exceptions*:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id webView;
```

Perhaps the best option is to declare a protocol to confine the *any type*:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<WebViewProtocol> webView;
```